# Viewing Passing Postgres Uniqueness Index Checks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a rails application with a migration to set a uniqueness index on the model for (some_field, some_timestamp). When I insert a row into the table, is there a way to see the postgres code that runs this uniqueness check for a passing case?

```
 hi = 'hi'
 hello = 'hello'
 timestamp = Date.current
```

Do the first insert

```
 SampleTable.create(some_field: hi, timestamp: timestamp)
```

When we do a subsequent insert, I want to see the postgres log that checks the uniqueness index. Currently, I see the uniquness index output for a failing case, but not a passing case. Is it possible to see the passing case?

For example, I see logs here for a failure case.

```
 SampleTable.insert(some_field: hi, timestamp: timestamp)
```

But I do not see logs for the success case.

```
 SampleTable.insert(some_field: hello, timestamp: timestamp)
```

In an ideal world, I'd like to see the granular output of 'hello' != 'hi', so uniqueness index is fine. Is this possible?

Example of logs for a (similar) failure case
[image]

Comment: Are you saying you want a way to print all the values that are already in the table? On every insert?

Comment: On every insert, I want the logs to show postgres's evaluation of my new potential entry against every existing entry.

Comment: (1) That's not how an index works and (2) even if it did that would quickly become impossible to manage, even with a table of only a few thousand rows. No such feature exists and if you want one you will have to implement it yourself with a patch to PostgreSQL's source-code.

Comment: (3) Why would you want to do that? The failure is clear and in the case of validation (which is what uniqueness is) lack of failure is success. As an aside you should not let this hit the database, validate up front instead.

Comment: I was just curious to see if it if was possible.